# Open window in new tab without user event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here I have two asp.net mvc websites . From first website i have one link to second website. So first website will call the second's action. I want to open on page in new tab and current tab should redirect to my first website. This action will return one view.

My approaches in view

1.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    window.open("/newpage");
    window.open("/site1", "_self"); 
});
```

Browser popup blocker will block this. Because there is no user event . So I tried different approach

2.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {   
    $("#input").on("click", function () {
        window.open("/newpage");
        window.open("/site1", "_self");
    });
    $("#input").trigger("click");
});

<label id="input" style="display:none;">test one</label>
```

I have triggered one event. But still its blocked. This two approaches is working fine if popup blocker is disabled. 
I want to open page in new tab without disable the popup blocker.

NOTE: This two website comes under same domain name . eg: abc.com\siteone and abc.com\sitetwo

Comment: You can't open a new window in most modern browsers unless a user initiated it, it's to avoid annoying popups.

Answer (score 0):

> From first website i have one link to second website. So first website will call the second's action. I want to open on page in new tab and current tab should redirect to my first website.

The way I've done this the once or twice that I had a really good use case for it was to use a link element with a click handler: The click handler opens the new window, and the link element's default action follows the link, taking the existing window to the new location. That way, it *is* a user-initiated action. This works in every browser I've tried it in. I should note that it tends *not* to work in things like jsFiddle or jsBin, because of how they wrap things.

So in your case, the link's `href` would be where you want them to go on the first website, and the `window.open` would be for the second website.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Double</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click me</a>
<script>
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() {
        window.open("http://google.com");
    },
    false
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to mention, you can't guarantee it will be a new tab and not a popup window. This is a user preference in many modern browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We won't get user initiated event here.

Comment: @Ram: I don't understand, you said *"From first website i have one link to second website"* -- clicking that link is a user-initiated event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My window.open not in first site, its in second site. After clicking a link in site 1 it will render the second website, from there we are opening  new window automatically  using window.open.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we don't have user initiated event in site2. Its only in site1 that is the problem.

Comment: @Ram: You don't need one in site2. In the example above, SO is site1 and Google is site2.